# Alterate the WordPress structure - Post flow is located in a page

Tags: wordpress, post, stream, structure

I have to create a WordPress site and I would like to know the best practice to make it. I have to respect these 2 things :

- The landing page is static
- The post stream is displayed in another page

Is there any module to automatically configure this structure alteration?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, that's standard WordPress functionality.  You create two pages (say "Landing" and "Post stream").  In the Reading settings (see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen)):

1. Set your "Front page displays" to "A static page"
2. Set "Front page" to "Landing"
3. Set "Posts page" to "Post stream"

and you're done.  Any content in "Post stream" will be replaced by your posts.